# Column of GroupLayout is Unaligned

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

The leftmost column is what I'm referencing here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXIcF.png]

About a week ago, I convinced my dad to ditch Windows 10 in favor of Linux Mint. The transition's been quite bumpy so far, considering how he likes to have a simplistic interface. He's not willing to work with the command line, so I've spent the better half of the day trying to make a java user interface so he'll quit his nagging on how he can't run a script. I do want it perfect, though, and this misalignment is annoying the heck out of me. I honestly don't understand what's different about that column compared to the others.

Here's my format method, which does all the GroupLayout stuff

```
    private void format() {
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING))
                .addComponent(inputLabel)
                .addComponent(outputLabel)
                .addComponent(exitButton)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                    .addComponent(inputTextField, 300, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(outputTextField, 300, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    )
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING).addComponent(inputButton).addComponent(outputButton)
                    .addComponent(compressButton)));

    layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, inputButton, outputButton);

    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                    .addComponent(inputLabel)
                    .addComponent(inputTextField, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(inputButton))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                    .addComponent(outputLabel)
                    .addComponent(outputTextField, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(outputButton))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                    .addComponent(exitButton)
                    .addComponent(compressButton)));

    setTitle("PDF CONVERTER");
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never learned to read the GroupLayout code generated by an IDE. For one reason the code is not portable if you ever move to another IDE. The drag/drop tool will generate different code. A simple solution is to use a `GridBagLayout`, then you are in full control of your simple grid layout. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for information and examples.

Comment: You are doing a big disservice to people by recommending the outdated and terrible GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the horizontal layout group. You did not finish the first two groups with a closing right round bracket.

I have also improved the code a bit. I supressed the vertical growing of text fields with a baseline alignment in a vertical group.

Also, it is preferable to define the number of expected columns in a text field rather that hardcoding the minimum size in a layout.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class PdfConverterEx extends JFrame {

    public PdfConverterEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel("Input:");
        JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("Output:");

        JTextField field1 = new JTextField(25);
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField(25);

        JButton browseBtn1 = new JButton("Browse");
        JButton browseBtn2 = new JButton("Browse");

        JButton exitBtn = new JButton("Exit");
        JButton compressBtn = new JButton("Compress");

        createLayout(inputLabel, outputLabel, field1, field2,
                browseBtn1, browseBtn2, exitBtn, compressBtn);

        setTitle("PDF Converter");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(arg[0])
                        .addComponent(arg[1])
                        .addComponent(arg[6]))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(arg[2])
                        .addComponent(arg[3]))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(arg[4])
                        .addComponent(arg[5])
                        .addComponent(arg[7]))
        );

        layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, arg[5], arg[6]);

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(arg[0])
                        .addComponent(arg[2])
                        .addComponent(arg[4]))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(arg[1])
                        .addComponent(arg[3])
                        .addComponent(arg[5]))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(arg[6])
                        .addComponent(arg[7])));

        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            PdfConverterEx ex = new PdfConverterEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

An good luck with the transition to Linux. :)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bundle, man! I hadn't even noticed that one blasted little parenthesis. I upvoted your answer, but my rep's too low to show. Just thought you should know.